# date of creation of a variable using R

Tags: r

Is there a way to document variables in R with their date of creation/modification?
Because I have .RData files that I used fluency, but sometimes need update the values based in how old is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `file.info()`:

To get the last modified time:

```
file.info('path/to/file.Rdata')$mtime
```

If you want to know when individual variables within your `.RData` object were last defined by R the only thing I know to do would be to manually add that metadata in something like this:

```
a = 3
attr(a, 'time_defined') = Sys.time()
b = 4
attr(b, 'time_defined') = Sys.time()

save(a, b, file = 'my_data.RData')

# ... later on ...

load('my_data.RData')

if(difftime(attr(a, 'time_defined'), Sys.time(), units = 'days') > 10) # do the following if more than 10 days old
```

Comment: In .Rdata I have two variables a and b. I set a yesterday and b today. Need both dates

Comment: Ahh I see. Updated for your clarification.